# how is componentDidCatch different than a try/catch in render?

Tags: reactjs

I was just reading about the react16 feature `componentDidCatch`, and this article for example recommends creating an error boundary component: http://www.deadcoderising.com/react-16-taking-control-of-your-errors-using-error-boundaries/.

And it leads me to wonder how that's different than a simple try catch in render, something like this:

```
const ErrorBoundary = ({children}) => {
    try {
        return children;
    } catch (ex) {
        return (
            <div>Something went wrong</div>
        );
    }
};
```

I assume there's some distinction otherwise the React team wouldn't have added a lifecycle method, but it's not clear to me what it is.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#why-not-use-try--catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Boy With Silver Wings posted in a comment, [React docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#why-not-use-try--catch) state it quite obviously:

> try / catch is great but it only works for imperative code:
>
> `try {   showButton(); } catch (error) {   // ... }`
>
> However, React
> components are declarative and specify what should be rendered:
>
> Error boundaries preserve the declarative nature of React,
> and behave as you would expect. For example, even if an error occurs
> in a componentDidUpdate hook caused by a setState somewhere deep in
> the tree, it will still correctly propagate to the closest error
> boundary.

Worth to note that Error Boundaries catch rendering errors. That means errors that happen during e.g. event handling won't get caught.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an example let's say you have a component that throws error inside useEffect hook:

```
const ComponentWithError = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    throw new Error('ooops')
  }, []);
  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

Let's say you use it in your ErrorBoundary:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <ComponentWithError />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

That would not show fallback as it would when using `componentDidCatch`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do other clean-up or app logic if an error is thrown, and the `render` method is a horrible place to do that. In general, you should do nothing in the `render` method other than render the content. In your example, it may not make any difference. As the app grows in complexity, there is a good chance you would want to do other things, like update redux state for example. The render method would not be an appropriate place to do that, but a lifecycle method (like `componentDidCatch`) might be.